# CSS flexible box menu stretch to 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexible box menu who will be stretched to fill 100% the height of the page.

Currently I can do that but I have to fix manually the number of box to 5 and the height to 20% (20% * 5 = 100% Hallelujah!!).

1. What I would like to achieve is the same thing whatever the number of boxes (boxes will be dynamically added to the DOM later on).
2. How would you do to place the text in the bottom right hand corner. Cannot manage to do that.

**I'd rather not use JQuery but only use CSS.**

Below is what I've done so far: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kgzOsUBeTXlM29GylXUy?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="box home">
            <a href="#home">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box about">
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box portfolio">
            <a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box services">
            <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box contact">
            <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
    color:#444;
    font-size:1.6em;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    height:auto;
}
.nav
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.box
{
    height:20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:200px;
}

.box.home { background-color: #2d89ef; }
.box.about { background-color: #00a300; }
.box.portfolio { background-color: #e3a21a; }
.box.services { background-color: #9f00a7; }
.box.contact { background-color: #ee1111; }

.box a
{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a flexbox layout, you could set the `display` of the `.nav` element to `flex`, and then add `flex-direction: column` in order to make the children elements flow vertically. In order to make the children `.box` elements stretch to fill the parent, you could simply add `flex-grow: 1`:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2CHfV7cvCpx5VRy7vnq?p=preview)

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```css
html, body, .container, .nav {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    color:#444;
    font-size:1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
}
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 200px;
}
.box.home { background-color: #2d89ef; }
.box.about { background-color: #00a300; }
.box.portfolio { background-color: #e3a21a; }
.box.services { background-color: #9f00a7; }
.box.contact { background-color: #ee1111; }
.box a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="box home">
            <a href="#home">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box about">
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box portfolio">
            <a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box services">
            <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box contact">
            <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In order to place the text at the bottom, set the `display` of the `.box` elements to `flex`, and add `justify-content: flex-end` in order to align the text to the right. Then add `align-self: flex-end` to the child `a` elements in order to place the text at the bottom:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NQq94KLZ6Q3Vkn756o2j?p=preview)

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.box a {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```css
html, body, .container, .nav {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    color:#444;
    font-size:1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
}
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.box a {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
.box.home { background-color: #2d89ef; }
.box.about { background-color: #00a300; }
.box.portfolio { background-color: #e3a21a; }
.box.services { background-color: #9f00a7; }
.box.contact { background-color: #ee1111; }
.box a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="box home">
            <a href="#home">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box about">
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box portfolio">
            <a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box services">
            <a href="#services">SERVICES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box contact">
            <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. As it did work on Chrome and Firefox I'm going to accept the answer but do you know why it doesn't work on Safari/iOS. I tried -webkit-box or -webkit-flex but it didn't change anything. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

To evenly distribute items vertically I would use a `<table>`, or the CSS `display:table` (etc.) equivalent.

Comment: I did try using display:table but couldn't manage to get it right. Could you please show me how you' do it? perhaps via plunker? thnks